# Access SignalR application running on localhost from browser on ssl

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, https, signalr

I have an application that can be downloaded from our website and runs on user PC.

This application provides connection between our hardware and our web application. It uses SignalR for communication.

Basically, I run SignalR server under WinForms application and have javascript client that tries to access it through `http://localhost:8084/signalR`.
Everything works fine when I use HTTP version of the web application, but fails, when I use HTTPS for my web application:

Most of the browsers don't allow unsecured connections from a secure page.

So, my question is how can I have self-signed certificate included in my software which installs certificate on user pc during installation and how can I make it work in the way that browsers not complaining about unsecured connection?

Comment: Did you see: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Sep/23/Hosting-SignalR-under-SSLhttps

Comment: @hadee Did you find a solution to your problem. I have the very same issue

Comment: @OscarHermosilla Not unfortunately. I solved the issue with having http request opened in new browser tab and passing user id to maintain authorization.

Comment: @Hadee I ended up changing my code from SignalR to Websockets

Answer (score 1):

If you run SignalR server on user PC each user must obtain the certificate for SignalR connection it launches. Self-signed certificate would be reasonable decision for an Intranet or development. It isn't safe enough for the internet. Another possible problem is retrieving name of the machine where SignalR is running. Certificate attaches to certain local machine(I could be wrong at this) and for connecting to client's application SignalR server you need to know the name of machine he uses. Migrating SignalR server from client to web app server will solve mentioned troubles.